# Is there way to automatically supply multiple input string to multiple raw_input()/input() inside single function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below code is against python 2 but for python 3 you can answer considering input() instead.

I have a "set_pwd()" (which could not be modified i.e. a part of 3rd party library):

```
def set_pwd():
    x = raw_input("Enter the pwd")
    y = raw_input("Confirm the pwd")
```

Now, own implemented function, which is trying to call the above mentioned set_pwd() in a way trying to enter the pwd. I am able to apply pwd text at the first prompt but unable to do it for subsequent one(for pwd confirmation). Code below:

```
def enter_pwd():
    import sys
    import StringIO
    f1 = sys.stdin
    f = StringIO.StringIO('My123PWD')
    sys.stdin = f
    set_pwd()  # Call to function
    f.close()
    sys.stdin = f1
```

I trying exploring f.next() (for StringIO) but dint helped. Thanks in advance.

Comment: python3 doesn't use `raw_input`.... Are you sure this should be tagged python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is tagged Python3 so I will give a Python3 answer but the code you provided is Python2.7.  You can pass multiple inputs by just using a newline (i.e. `\n`):

```
from io import StringIO
import sys


def set_pwd():
    x = input("Enter the pwd")
    y = input("Confirm the pwd")
    print()
    print("X:", x) # My123PWD
    print("Y:", y) # confirmed

f = StringIO('My123PWD\nconfirmed')
sys.stdin = f
set_pwd()  # Call to function
f.close()
sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__ # sys remembers stdin so just use this to restore it
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it solved the question :).